# Select newest rows related to new rows with value between dates

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with four fields: parent_id, field_name, field_value and inserted_at.

I need to find all of the newest rows under a parent id, when the value of a row of the 'date' field name is between date 1 and date 2.

Current sql does not return rows between the dates, it returns some older rows too. I think it'd work if I could put a window expression in the where clause, but right now with subqueries and a CTE something is not carrying over in the joins and letting bad data back in.

```
SELECT all_fields.parent_id, all_fields.field_name, all_fields.field_value FROM (
      WITH sorted_table AS (
        SELECT newest_rows.parent_id from (
          SELECT
            row_number() over (partition by o3.parent_id, o3.field_name order by o3.inserted_at desc) as row_n,
            parent_id
          FROM table o3
          where field_name = 'date'
          and field_value between '2019-01-01' and '2019-01-30'
        )
        as newest_rows
        WHERE newest_rows.row_n = 1
      )
      SELECT row_number() over (partition by o3.parent_id, o3.field_name order by o3.inserted_at desc) as row_n, o3.parent_id, o3.field_name, o3,field_value
      FROM table o3
      left join sorted_table so
      on so.parent_id = o3.parent_id
    ) as all_fields
    WHERE all_fields.row_n = 1;
```

given database rows:

```
parent_id   field_name  field_value inserted_at
1           date        jan 25      july 1
1           date        feb 2       july 2
1           name        frank       july 1
1           name        nancy       july 3
2           date        dec 3       july 1
2           date        jan 5       july 2
2           name        allison     july 1
2           name        debbie      july 2
3           date        dec 1       july 1
3           date        jan 6       july 2
3           name        roger       july 1
3           name        claire      july 3
```

date range: jan 1-30

results should be:

```
parent_id   field_name  field_value inserted_at
2           date        jan 5       july 2
2           name        debbie      july 2
3           date        jan 6       july 2
3           name        claire      july 3
```

date field is newest and within range so it returns all newest rows for each field_name under parent_id.

Comment: Why isn't Alison returned?

Comment: because it's older than  debbie. i need the newest row of every field name. i'll clarify that in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your field values are in a reasonable format (i.e. YYYY-MM-DD).  Then the parent_id with the maximum date is provided by:

```
select o3.*
from o3
where field_name = 'date' and
      field_value >= '2019-01-01' and
      field_value < '2019-02-01'
order by field_value desc
limit 1;
```

Then I think you want:

```
select o3.*
from o3
where (parent_id, inserted_at) = (
          (select o3.parent_id, o3.inserted_at
           from o3
           where o3.field_name = 'date' and
                 o3.field_value >= '2019-01-01' and
                 o3.field_value < '2019-02-01'
           order by o3.field_value desc
           limit 1
          );
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken that'd only return one row with a very particular inserted_at date? I need all the newest rows, I've added more rows to my example to illustrate that.

Comment: @AngelaKay . . . You are mistaken.  The query will return all rows that match the parent id/inserted date of the latest field value in the range.

Comment: It would only work if the newest inserted_at dates for all fields are the same date.